# How to set two child in firestore collection ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can i change realtime firebase code into firestore. In my code two child is given to get user follow button status is true or false.

Here is the realtime firebase code:

```
  func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

      REF_FOLLOWERS.child(userId).child(Api.User.CURRENT_USER!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
            completed(false)            } else { 
           completed(true)
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the code which i have tried to get in firestore:

```
    func isFollowing(userId: String, completed: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {



    let docRef = db.collection("followers").document(userId)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
            completed(document.data())

        } else {

            completed(nil)
        }
    }


}
```

Note: In realtime Firebase they have given userid and current user uid but Firestore can't able to give user id and current user uid.